# Excel to handle inventory list - control and count items

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create excel sheet of inventory list.
I have a given list of items (laptop, monitor, keyboard, etc..) and a group of people.
I saw it is called data validation.
my question is how can i sum the number of monitors the organization has, and how can i sort the items of a certain person.

thanks

Comment: This is where spreadsheets stop and databases should begin.  If your expecting any kind of growth you'll need a database version sooner rather than later.  There are templates like: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/templates/inventory-management-database-TC001018458.aspx to help you get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple example would be a simple table with your staff on the left one on top of the other and the items on the top. For each member of staff that has a specific item put the number of items they have in the applicable cell. The use SUM() to calculate the total number of each item...

[image]

Here item 1 could be the number of laptops each person has, person 3 having 2. Item 2 could be the number of monitors each person has and item 3 the number of mouse's each person has.

You can replace the blank cells with a 0 without it changing the results.

Comment: I guess all his items are in a single column but without a sample file its hard to tell.

Comment: His first line indicates that he has only the raw information atm ("I need to create...") so my guess was that he could just set up a spread sheet like my example above and enter the info as read from his raw material. But as you said, without more information there is no way to know.